# Using the De Moivre–Laplace theorem (Voters)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> $100,000$ voters participate in an election between Proposition $A$
> and Proposition $B$. Among them are $300$ who are determined to vote
> for Proposal A. The rest are undecided and (in our model) decide
> independently between the two proposals by a fair coin toss. How
> likely is it that Proposal $A$ will receive the majority? How likely
> is it if the coin toss is instead in favor of Proposal $B$ with
> probability $p=0.505$.

**My answer**

We first have $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(99700,0.5,k)$. $99700$ since $300$ have already made their decision. We have to take these out of the random model, since their choice is no longer random - they still have to be taken into account when determining the majority. Among the remaining voters, $A$ needs at least $\frac{100000}{2}-300=49700$ votes. We have $\mu=49850$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{49850\cdot 0.5}\approx 157.877>3$. Applying Moivre-Laplace's theorem to the approximation, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
P\left(X>\frac{100000}{2}-300\right)&=P(X>49700)=1-P(X\leq 49700)  \\ 
& =1-\Phi\left(\frac{49700-49850+0.5}{157.877}\right)   \\
& =1-\Phi(-0.95)=1-(1-\Phi(0.95))=0.82894
\end{align*}
For the second part, we assume $p=0.505$ for $B$, and thus  $p_A=1-0.505=0.495$. The computation now is essentially the same, but we have $\mu_A=99700\cdot 0.495=49351.5$ und $\sigma_A=\sqrt{24601.5\cdot 0.495}=156.298>3$ and:
\begin{align*}
P\left(X>\frac{100000}{2}-300\right)&=P(X>49700)=1-P(X\leq 49700)  \\ 
& =1-\Phi\left(\frac{49700-49351.5+0.5}{156.298}\right)   \\
& =1-\Phi(2.23)=1-0,98713=0.01287
\end{align*}

Is this correct? Can someone confirm these computations?

Comment: They're pretty much right. Keep in mind that those are approximations. You have tight approximations up to the 2nd digital digit.